# C# Redirecting console output from Unity game server

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, console

So, I'm making a bot that will start/stop/update my Unturned 3.0 servers (Unity) without me needing to interact with my Windows dedicated server. As it sits, I've managed to get the server starting. I would like to redirect the StandardOutput of the console to my c# console app so I can send a message to discord saying the server is online and start accepting commands (like listing online players), however I can't manage to get past this one roadblock. Every time I try to redirect standard output, all i get is

```
Mono path[0] = 'E:/SteamCMD/servers/rust/RustDedicated_Data/Managed'
Mono path[1] = 'E:/SteamCMD/servers/rust/RustDedicated_Data/Mono'
Mono config path = 'E:/SteamCMD/servers/rust/RustDedicated_Data/Mono/etc'
```

After that, no text is displayed in either the unturned console that opens, or my c# console app (the server still starts normally). I've been all over google trying to find someone with a similar problem, but the closest I've found requires me to call a unity function, and my program is a third party program that has no affiliation with unity (beyond the fact that it starts a unity gameserver).

Here's my current code, however I've been through so many iterations trying to find something that works that this isn't the only code (I've been at this for over a day now with no luck)

```
using Discord.WebSocket;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace GameBot
{
    static class StartUnturned
    {
        private static IniFile ini = iniSettings.gamebotIni();
        internal static async void startNewInstance(string serverName)
        {
            var t = new Task(() =>
            {
                Process p = new Process();
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
                p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
                p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
                p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                p.StartInfo.FileName = ini.IniReadValue("unturned", "installdirectory") + @"\Unturned.exe";
                p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-logFile \"Servers\\" + serverName + "\\Rocket\\Unturned.log\" -nographics -batchmode -silent-crashes +secureserver/" + serverName;
                p.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
                p.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => {
                        Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            });
                p.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler((s, e) => {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
            });

                p.Start();
                p.BeginOutputReadLine();
                p.WaitForExit();
                while (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() != null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
                }
            });

            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                t.Start();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

`private static IniFile ini = iniSettings.gamebotIni();` is a class to write to/read from an ini file that i found on the web a long time ago, this is only used to get the starting path of Unturned.exe (currently `C:\Unturned\`)

Also, I'm using tasks because I plan to run multiple of these servers at once and want to interact with them individually based on the server name passed (ie, in discord a staff member could type `!unturned pvp listplayers` and it will list players on pvp). If there is a better way to do this, I am wholly open to suggestions.

Comment: Have you proven that Unturned actually produces console output by starting it manually from cmd.exe with the startup options you have there?  Also the last bit `while (p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd() != null)` will probably create a deadlock after WaitForExit or will throw an exception.

Comment: Normally output_log.txt is written in the *_Data folder next to the game executable, where Debug.Log output is printed. There is no StandardOutput.  You'll need to write a simple `log tailer` to pull new Debug.Log output from that file as they're written.

Comment: Yes, Unturned definitely outputs to the console with the same parameters when run from cmd, and the while loop was one of my random tests, it does throw an exception when closing, but even with the code removed it has the same behavior

Comment: What output are you getting?  What's driving that output? Debug.Log or something else you've crafted inside your game to produce it?

Comment: The game is not mine, it is Unturned, coded by Nelson of Smartly Dressed Games. I am looking to make a discord bot that starts/stops gameservers I run for his game

Comment: This is what normally happens when I launch the gameserver in CMD
https://gyazo.com/2a55bf7bec699b0027409b23dc4ce7e8

This is what happens when I launch the gameserver from my console app (this is a gif)
https://gyazo.com/21bf20af8d5d1d5cc9dd0f8653129272

Comment: Did you try with `p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;` ?